# Laminations and current capacity,

Tags: electromagnetism

When a conductor **that's purpose is to carry current** ,is laminated to reduce eddy currents, does it affect the current capacity for that same conductor? Will it reduce the current capacity?

Comment: Probably not, but even if it did, why would it matter? The core is not what is carrying the current, the wires are. And the wires are not laminated to reduce eddy currents, only the core is.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofusSorry, I edited my questions. It does carry current.

Comment: Could you give an example of a situation where this is done? I don't really have any EE background. I know this is done for laminated iron cores in transformers (where individual laminated sheets of iron are stacked to form the core), but that's for a different purpose than laminating a wire.

Comment: Well, think of a generator that has a large thick conductor in a powerful magnetic field. Aside from the EMF induced, there will be massive eddy currents on the surface that create a force opposing the motion. Why not laminate the conductor to reduce those eddy currents? And it was indeed laminated, would the current capacity of that conductor be reduced by the process? Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Why would laminating the conductor reduce the eddy currents at all? The lamination itself doesn't reduce eddy currents, the breakup of the conductor into multiple smaller elements with insulating boundaries does. I doubt it would change the current-carrying capacity; I've never seen advertisers rate wires of the same thickness with different coatings with different current-handling capacities, for example.

Comment: Could you please explain the physics of that concept? Why would breaking the conductor into smaller and thinner pieces would reduce eddy currents?

Comment: See http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/power_loss.html and scroll down to the section called "Eddy current loss". In particular, it concludes "eddy current loss is inversely proportional to the square of the number of laminations", ie, inversely proportional to the square of the number of pieces the conductor is broken into. So if you break it into 5 pieces, the eddy current loss decreases by a factor of 25.